# AMQP Version for Older RabbitMQ Instance

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, amqp

I have an older version of RabbitMQ that is having trouble getting new entries in the queue when using Ruby's [AMQP](http://rubyamqp.info/) plugin.  Looking at their README.md, they state that [older RabbitMQ instances may not work with newer versions of the AMQP library.](https://github.com/ruby-amqp/amqp#install-rabbitmq)  Unfortunately the linked document doesn't exist, and looking inside the /docs/ folder of the repo looks to contain outdated information.

So my question is this, what implementation of the AMQP protocol does RabbitMQ `v2.6.1` use?  Would `v2.6.1` be supported by newer versions of the AMQP Ruby Gem?

Comment: you cant simply upgrade RabbitMQ instances?\

Comment: @Clustermagnet Nope, not yet.  Got to replace the old system first!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at this [article](http://instantbadger.blogspot.com/2010/07/cannot-redeclare-exchange-error-on-amqp.html) it would seem that 1.7.x of RabbitMQ use the AMQP specs of 0.8 and 1.8.x+ uses 0.9.  Ideally the AMQP ruby gem should have worked, however I ended up just using bunny.

> This is significant because RMQ 1.8 uses AMQP 0.9, whereas v1.7.2 uses AMQP 0.8